# Decrypt OAEP with PublicKey in iOS

Tags: ios, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, pkcs#1

I'm a student who have some very rudimentary theoretical knowledge about RSA. I'm studying the next hypothetical situation but I'm very confused and I need some help to solve it.

In my situation I have a server which encrypt data with RSA using its Private Key (So I far as I know this is a signature schema). The chosen padding of this encryption is PKCS1_OAEP_SHA1 This is my first doubt, is this situation correct? or I should use PKCS1_PSS instead of PKCS1_OAEP_SHA1?

Then the server sends its PublicKey to an iPhone mobile phone in order to decrypt/verify the previously encrypt/sign data. But according with Apple's CryptoCompatiblity manifest http://goo.gl/81Um6Z iOS only supports PKCS1 and none padding decrypt. 
So my second question it is how to decrypt OAEP PublicKey in a supported format in iOS. And in the case that I would have signed with PKCS1_PSS in first place (instead of PKCS1_OAEP) Can I verify it in iOS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OEAP (PKCS#1 v2.0) is better than PKCS#1 v1.5, but you'll have to use the latter if OAEP is not supported.

Comment: But I have no control about the server side. PublicKey is in OAEP format. So I have to find the way of verify it (PublicKey OAEP) in iOS (PKCS#1 or none padding format)...

Answer (score 1):

You should never use OAEP padding to encrypt "signatures". Signatures should be generated by signature generation algorithm such as [PSS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-29). Although the modular exponentiation part of the encryption and signature generation algorithms is identical (as noted in the standard) the padding method is not.

Note that PSS is better than PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures (provable secure). You may however fall back to [PKCS#1 v1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-32) signatures if you run into compatibility issues between libraries.

For your specific situation: you can decrypt using RSA/NONE and then perform the OAEP unpadding yourself. That is tricky to implement though.

Note that the given protocol is *not secure* against man in the middle attacks; how do you trust the public key that is send? An attacker may simply replace it by his own key.